# How can I perform a d3 nested data-join where the child references data from the parent?

Tags: svg, d3.js

First I create a selection and add a few things to it. I've stripped it down for readability:

```
arcData = [
    {data: [{label: "first"}], otherProp: value},
    {data: [{label: "second"}], otherProp: value}];

arcSelection = svg.selectAll("arc").data(arcData);

arcSelection.enter().append("g").append("path").attr("d", myArcDefinition);
```

I try to add a nested selection using data from the parent:

```
arcDataSelection = arcSelection.selectAll("text").data(function(singleArc, arcIndex) {
  return singleArc;
});
arcDataSelection.enter().append("text").text(function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
});
```

But no `text` objects are created in the DOM. How can I properly create an element in a nested selection that uses data from a parent?

I'm trying to follow the pattern(s) shown here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use nested selections, you need to have nested data. You're passing in a one-dimensional array (i.e. not nested). Have another look at the example you've linked to -- the data used there is a two-dimensional array.